# Eigenvectors of asymmetric graphs

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, automorphism-groups, eigenvector

Let $G$ be an asymmetric connected graph. Then is it always the case that at least one of the eigenvectors of its adjacency matrix $A$ consists entirely of distinct entries?

Thanks!

Comment: By asymmetric, you mean the automorphism group is trivial?

Comment: Yes, the graph has a trivial automorphism group. And yes I'm assuming a connected graph. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm curious what was the motivation for the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is no. Take the [Frucht Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph), the simplest nontrivial asymmetric graph. Its adjacency matrix is

\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}

none of whose eigenvectors seems to have distinct entries.

Comment: If I entered it correctly into Maple then three of the 12 distinct eigenvalues do have eigenvectors with distinct entries.

Comment: I cut and pasted the above matrix into Mathematica and it seems that all eigenvectors have repeated entries.

Comment: Ok, I agree.I think I got fooled when Maple took equal but not identically written algebraic integers and evaluated them slightly differently numerically.

Comment: Funny that I had checked the Frucht graph before asking this question and hadn't noticed that all eigenvectors' entries were not distinct. Well spotted.